# Wrapping anchor link and text node inside li tag (and excluding the ul tag)?

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
<li>
  <a></a>
  "(1)"
  <ul></ul>
</li>
```

I want it to end up something like this:

```
<li>
  <span>
    <a></a>
    "(1)"
  </span>
  <ul></ul>
</li>
```

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ul = $('li ul');
$('li ul').remove();
$('li').wrapInner('<span>');
$('li').append($ul);
```

Works. See http://jsfiddle.net/Lhg32/ (thanks for the comment!)

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = $('li').clone(true),
         ul = content.children('ul').remove();

$('li').html($('<span />').append(content.contents()).append(ul));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3AKg/)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have a lot of li in the same page. How do I apply that to only the current parent?

Comment: You need to add a class or ID, or target a parent element that has a class or ID, or use the index of the element etc. Anything really, but from the HTML you posted it's impossible to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/lamarant/XjQek/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>This is Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1 Sub 1</li>
            <li>Item 1 Sub 2</li>
            <li>Item 1 Sub 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>This is Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 1</li>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 2</li>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 3</li>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('ul li').not('ul ul li').each(function () {
        var $clone = $(this).clone(true);
        var $origUL = $('ul', $(this)).first();
        var $newUL = $('<ul></ul>');
        $newUL.html($origUL.html());
        $clone.children('ul').remove();
        $(this).html('').append($('<span>' + $clone.html().trim() + '</span>')).append($newUL);
    });
```

**Result**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>This is Item 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1 Sub 1</li>
            <li>Item 1 Sub 2</li>
            <li>Item 1 Sub 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>This is Item 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 1</li>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 2</li>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 3</li>
            <li>Item 2 Sub 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$('li a').before('&lt;span&gt;');
$('li ul').before('&lt;/span&gt;');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I honestly don't believe it will. If you can show me a demo that shows this working as you expect it to, and not as I expect it to, then I'll reverse my down-vote.